# Azure Logic Apps standard parse JSON error

Tags: json, azure, whmcs, azure-logic-app-standard

Whenever I pass a simple JSON and simple schema with the parse JSON card in logic apps something like

```
{
   "Hello":"World"
}
```

and

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Hello": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

It processes naturally, but if I try to access the data from an API call from WHMCS GetClientsProducts via an HTTP request I get an error.

schema

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "result": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "clientid": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serviceid": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "pid": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "domain": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "totalresults": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "startnumber": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "numreturned": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "products": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "product": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "clientid": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "orderid": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "ordernumber": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "pid": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "regdate": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "translated_name": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "groupname": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "translated_groupname": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "domain": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "dedicatedip": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "serverid": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "servername": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "serverip": {},
                            "serverhostname": {},
                            "suspensionreason": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "firstpaymentamount": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "recurringamount": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "paymentmethod": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "paymentmethodname": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "billingcycle": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "nextduedate": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "status": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "username": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "password": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "subscriptionid": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "promoid": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "overideautosuspend": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "overidesuspenduntil": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ns1": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "ns2": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "assignedips": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "notes": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "diskusage": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "disklimit": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "bwusage": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "bwlimit": {
                                "type": "integer"
                            },
                            "lastupdate": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "customfields": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "customfield": {
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "name": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "translated_name": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "value": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "configoptions": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "configoption": {
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "id": {
                                                    "type": "integer"
                                                },
                                                "option": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "value": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though this schema was generated with the payload that I am requesting for within the HTTP Request prior to the Parse JSON card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I faced the similar issue.

[image]

This is because the body that is received from trigger body is not of json type (string type). Once I replaced `triggedBody()` with `json(triggedBody())` I could able to get the desired result.

[image]

I have taken a sample data from your provided schema and did the same as below.

To make the process easy, First try to select the property that is required.

[image]

Then navigate to your code view and replace code as below.

[image]

[image]

```
"For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose": {
                        "inputs": "@items('For_each')?['customfields']",
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@json(triggerBody())?['products']?['product']",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Foreach"
            }
```

*Results:*

[image]